# Объяснение конструкции std::hash в С++

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, хеширование, hashmap

Разбираюсь в построении `std::hash` в C++ и возник вопрос, почему конструкция выглядит так

```
std::hash<std::string>{}(data)?
```

Т.е. почему это было сделано как функтор (если я правильно понимаю), а не просто функция хеширования? Фактически получается, что мы можем создать структуру (например, `hasher`), а потом вызывать оператор. И этот вариант тоже подходит:

```
std::hash<std::string> hasher;
unsigned int hash = hasher(data);
```

или так

```
std::hash<std::string> hasher{};
unsigned int hash = hasher(data);
```

На англоязычных ресурсах есть объяснение, что "`std::hash` является функтором, а не просто функцией, потому что он может иметь состояние”. А в каком случае нужно? Помогите, пожалуйста, на каком-то конкретном примере понять необходимость именно того, что это функтор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вначале самый банальный аргумент. Функциональный объект это класс/структура. А значит можно иметь приватные переменные и функции. А это позволяет писать более инкапсулированный код. Также никто не отменял наследования и подобных удобств ООП.

Но есть другой пункт - считается, что функциональные объекты лучше поддаются оптимизации, чем указатели на функцию. И функциональные объекты значительно легче инлайнить. [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809985/are-functors-actually-faster-than-pointers-to-functions), [пример 2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Writing_efficient_code/Performance_improving_features). В книгах Маерса много об этом. Также я видел эту рекомендацию в многих код-стандартах в разных компаниях (разглашать их я не могу по причинам NDA). А лишние пару процентов производительности никогда не были лишними.

И на последок, а зачем может понадобится состояние? Представьте себе, что Вы хотите считать среднее арифметическое, максимальное и минимальное за один проход. Можно написать ручками, а можно использовать `for_each` и правильный функтор, который предоставит на выходе все сразу. Да, пример надуманный, но вполне можно представить себе код, который обрабатывает файлы в каталоге рекурсивно. И без функционального объекта нужно иметь отдельно функции, отдельно структуры, а ещё возможность связать это все вместе. И в конце концов Вы прийдете к тому, что Вам нужен класс, который содержит все это...

Comment: Большое спасибо за примеры